# How to get vendor and app chunks in webpack 4 with server side rendering?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

The idea is very simple - to get vendor.js and app.js files using webpack 4. All examples from [docs](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/) don't work. Because webpack creates bundle.js, 1.bundle.js, 2.bundle.js... I'm using server side rendering and React-Loadable.